# Mysql: Insert row with default new data for each user

Tags: mysql

Grateful for help with a tricky (for me) query. I am very much a mysql beginner.

The table (v3_community_fields_values) has the following columns:

- id (unique id of the row, autoincrements)
- user_id (the id of the user)
- field_id (the id of the field type)
- value (the values of that
  field)
- access

I have been scratching my head how to write a query that inserts a row for each user where:
a) no such row already exists, and
b) another user row exists with [field_id] of 45 (45 = user profile type) and the value of either 5 or 6

the new row should contain: [id],[user_id],'75','foobar'

Very grateful for your help.

Comment: By 'another user row exists with [field_id] of 45', do you mean you actually want to insert two rows for each user, one is ([id],[user_id],'75','foobar') another is ([id],[user_id],'45','5/6')?

Comment: No sorry, for each user_id there will already be a row with a field_id of 45 and value of a single digit either 1,5 or 6 (which correspond to a profile type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does it (tested):

```
insert into v3_community_fields_values
    (user_id, field_id, value)
select user_id, 75, 'foo'
from v3_community_fields_values
where field_id = 45
and value in ('5', '6')
and user_id not in (
select user_id
from v3_community_fields_values
where field_id = 75)
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac64f7/2) on SQLFiddle.

Comment: Thanks - I get the error: #1146 - Table 'profr192_v3_st4.user' doesn't exist

Comment: What is your user table called? Users? Let me know

Comment: the user table is _users but I'm not sure that is necessary. The table v3_community-fields_values has the user_id column which is the same user_id as the users table. I changed your query so line 3 was "from v3_community_fields_values and ran it on a test copy of the database and it inserted 150 odd rows, which is not right. There are thousands of user records this should apply to. Also it inserted multiple field_id 75 rows for each user_id which is not right. Each row with a user_id of x should only have one entry with a field_id of y.

Comment: I have completely reworked and improved the query and tested it (and it works). Also see link to demo.

Comment: You nailed it. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to implement using one sql statement, but this store procedure may help:

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists insert_something//
create procedure insert_something ()
begin
    DECLARE v_user_id int default 0;
    DECLARE stop int default 0;
    DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR select DISTINCT user_id from v3_community_fields_values where field_id = 45;    
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET stop=1;
    OPEN cursor1;
    FETCH cursor1 INTO v_user_id;
    while stop <> 1 do
        insert into v3_community_fields_values (user_id, field_id, `value`) values (v_user_id, '75', 'foobar');
        FETCH cursor1 INTO v_user_id;
    end while;
    CLOSE cursor1;
end //
call insert_something()//
```

Comment: wow - lots there I need to learn! Perhaps I should mention that I only need to perform this query once? as I have just created a new field and i want a specific set of users to have a default value. Does that make a difference. Is this complexity still needed? I will be firing it straight from phpmyadmin

Comment: Though I haven't used phpmyadmin before, but I think you can just copy and paste this code into phpmyadmin and run it. It basically just inserts a new line with value ([user_id],'75','foobar') for each [user_id] that is already in the table.

Comment: Thanks - I was about to test when I noticed there does not appear to be anything limiting the inserts to those users who have the field_id 45 and value 5 or 6...

Comment: Thanks for updating. I get the following error in phpmyadmin:

ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 549
STR: //

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'v_user_id, '75', 'foobar';
        FETCH cursor1 INTO v_user_id;
    end while' at line 10